# Output a Div to Text File

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I know i asked a similar question, but this is way more general. Is there any way of saving a div (with a determinated class) content to a text file, in the current directory, on server side, and something that don't require the user to click, because i have 500+ pages to save the same div, every day. It can be in php (if used in a main page, to parse other html files), jquery, ajax, anything.

The pages looks like this

```
...
<div class="myClass">
*lots of stuff*
*lots of stuff*
*lots of stuff*
</div>
...
```

and every page have a different name, ex: 475.html, and it would output to 475.txt the .myclass div. Inside this div, i have some more divs, some, uls, lis, and etc.

I don't know ajax, i know a little bit of PHP, and some of jQuery.
But i know, jscript alone won't let you access the filesystem by security reasons.
So if possible, be very clear, and poit me the way.

Thank you :)

Comment: What event do you want to invoke the file-save? It has to be something. Do you just want to iterate over each file and do this to each?

Comment: Maybe opening a main page with a php code to parse every other page and output, or some magic with js + ajax, on page launch (it would take much more time, right?). yes, over each file, and doing it to each. Is that possible?

Comment: Why are you seeking this functionality? I have a feeling you're making something that should be simple more complex than it needs to be.

Comment: Me and my gf, are developing a Phonegap App for the bus timetable of our city. The timetable change everytime, and is ONLY avaiable in the conpany website, as a complete webpage, making you have to access the internet to check the timetable. And we are making it offline, and mobile. First, i would need to copy / output the timetables to a file (they used ul / li in the website), then i would mold the data and give it the adequade treatment to fit our app, and insert to a database. Simple stuff. But i'm having trouble gathering JUST the timetables =P

Comment: Can you share the link to the company website?

Comment: sure, http://www.urbs.curitiba.pr.gov.br/horario-de-onibus/374 take a look

Comment: I think originally he means that he wants to get div or ul content from live site and save it to text file, and that savet text file has all the markup from inside ul or div like li href etc

Answer (score 0):

```
        $fileName = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; // Gets the filename
        $fileName = str_replace('/',"",$fileName); //removes "/" string
        $fileName = str_replace('.html',"",$fileName); //removes ".html" string
        $myFile = "$fileName.txt";
        $fh = fopen($myFile, 'w') or die("can't open file");
        $stringData = '<div class="myClass">............';
        fwrite($fh, $stringData);
        fclose($fh);
```

is that what you want?

Comment: i'm not sure, i'm kinda new to php, it was suposed to copy the entire <div class="myclass"> ... blablabla ... </div> and copy it (formated, if possible), to a txt.
I have been studying it for a while, and i just can't find a way to make it work,

Comment: then it's what you need! make a test.php and copy this script between <?php HERE ?> and run ir you should get a test.php.txt with conent of <dic class="myClass">....... make html file with headers to read php and it will save it to test.txt with the same content...

Comment: The Div is hosted on an external site

Comment: actually, i would 'wget' the html files, to work just on server side (apache + php on my computer).